# Using separate fonts for two different languages

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to use two different fonts for two different languages. But both fonts are overlapping eachother hence causing difficulty in reading the text. Here is what I am trying;

### CSS:

```
@font-face {
       font-family: 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq';
       src: url(../../../fonts/Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.ttf)
}
```

and then in the area where my `text` is written this CSS class has been used:

### CSS:

```
.post_body {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Jameel Noori Nastaleeq;
}
```

The issue is, when I use `URDU` text in my post it shows correct font style, however when I use `ENGLISH` text then it doesn't uses `Tahoma` font style.

Please help on how to use two different font styles for two different languages in the same area?

Comment: you can create 2 css files and then switch them using jquery

Comment: Hi himanshu, can you please give me any answer to this? I'm bigginer in this jQuery language.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by setting the language of the html...  ...or the language of the element.

```
<!-- html -->
<html lang="en">


/* CSS */
.post_body {
    /* common style stuff -- don't set font-family here */
}

:lang(en) .post_body {
    font-family : Tahoma;
}
```

Then use JS to change the `document.documentElement.lang` property.

That, of course, is if the whole page is changing language.

If you want to have some posts in Urdu and some posts in English at the same time, set

```
<article class="post_body" lang="en">

.post_body:lang(en) { font-family : Tahoma; }
```

Comment: nice solution and nicely explained, +1 for you :)

Comment: It doesn't worked, I've tried this CSS but it doesn't helps: 

 .post_body {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
 }

 .post_body:lang(en){
  font-family: Tahoma;
 }

 .post_body:lang(ur){
  font-family: Jameel Noori Nastaleeq;
 }

Comment: And you set the lang="en" on the element, in HTML, right?  The CSS isn't going to do much good if the lang isn't set on the element.