# How to set different font-family for 2 language in one paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a text content in my html (wordpress), which contain 2 language - Hebrew and English.
I'm trying to find **in the text**, just the string in English and give theme different font-family. 
I don't want to use inline style for each string.
I need to use regex or something, to find in my "p" tag, those strings and give theme the specific font that i want.
how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using separate fonts for two different languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052713/using-separate-fonts-for-two-different-languages)

Comment: add an example of your content to your question along with the desired output and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Example: https://ibb.co/dcmejb

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I found that I needed my application to deliver any and all Hebrew (and a lot of other languages, for that matter) with a few critical pieces.

```
<p> Your english here, <span lang="he" dir="rtl">your hebrew here</span></p>
```

Having to have those extra pieces gave me a selector for my css

```
*[lang='he'] {
  font-family: yourFont;
}
```

If you want to do it right, this may be the only way without using seriously complicated javascript.

Comment: it didn't solve my problem because [lang='he'] change font-family when the browser is in the 'he' language. in my case, i need to change the font-family not deepens on the browser language.. just find string and change font for it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'm saying set the language for each element, not the document as a whole. (Although, you should set the default, of course.) This worked on my site (language testing site), but it may have restraints I'm not aware of. Sorry! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping one language in `<span>` and applying a css class to it will work nicely and you won't need to use inline css styling.

```css
.french{
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color:red;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="french">Ceci est un exemple.</span> this is is an example. <span class="french">Ceci est un exemple.</span></p>
```

Comment: i d'ont want to wrap any string in span. i need to find in text the string using regex or something, and change font for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic flow of how you would do this in pseudo-code:

1. loop through the string and test each character against `/[a-zA-Z]+/g` if there is a match you know that that character is in English
2. When you find a match store that index
3. Starting from the stored index loop through the remaining characters until you find hit the character where the Regexp evaluates to false and store that index
4. Now that you have the beginning and end indices of the string you need to wrap them with a span that has a class of 'englishText' so for example:

   `var newText = yourText.slice(0, beginIndex) + '<span class="englishText>" + yourText.slice(beginIndex, endIndex) + "</span>" + yourText.slice(endIndex);`
5. Set the inner HTML of the your original text element to `newText`

This should work for the basic case that there is only one occurrence of English text, if there is more than on occurrence you will need to store the begin and end indices in arrays and built out the string using them.

Comment: hi.  i use this way and this is my code for now:   $("p:contains('" + newText + "')").html(function(_, html) {
   return  html.replace(newText , '<span class="red">$1</span>')
});          // newText is my variable with the string, but the replace function not working. what am i missing?

Comment: Where is your regex finding the match that is stored in $1?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution when your font don't support another language.**

For example - your font in Hebrew and in English it fall back to some unwanted default.
(this solution won't be helpful for cases you want to choose another font for the second language).

For all those that encounter this problem, there is a much simpler solution.
I found it due to assistance from the font-creator.

The solution is to insert the css font family, other desired font-family for English (or another language).

for example:

```
.my-class{
  font-family: 'not_support_english', fantasy, sans-serif !important;
}
```